# Proof about Newton: Homework

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Picture]

A mass hangs from three ropes (as shown in the Picture).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: what do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know how to proof F1=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_1cos(\Theta_1) = F_2cos(\Theta_2)$ balancing in the x-direction

$F_1sin(\Theta_1) + F_2sin(\Theta_2) = mg $ balancing in the y-direction

Using the first equation

$F_1sin(\Theta_1) + F_1\frac{cos(\Theta_1)*sin(\Theta_2)}{cos(\Theta_2)} = mg $

$F_1sin(\Theta_1)cos(\Theta_2) + F_1cos(\Theta_1)*sin(\Theta_2) = mg*cos(\Theta_2)$

Using the trigonometric identity we have

$ F_1sin(\Theta_1+\Theta_2) = mgcos(\Theta_2)$

Hence $ F_1 = \frac{mg*cos(\Theta_2)}{sin(\Theta_1+\Theta_2)}$

Comment: Your welcome :)